# How do I get the "Most read" module to show only articles within a time range

Tags: module, overrides

I am trying to display only the most read content from two months ago.

I have tried checking through mod_article_popular/helper.php file but can't figure out how to use the $model->setState to get what I want.

How can I get only articles within a date range to display?

Answer (score 3):

You should be looking at ContentModelArticles class for which filter states to manipute.  inside the classes getStoreId method is the answer:

```
protected function getStoreId($id = '')
{
    // Compile the store id.
    $id .= ':' . serialize($this->getState('filter.published'));
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.access');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.featured');
    $id .= ':' . serialize($this->getState('filter.article_id'));
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.article_id.include');
    $id .= ':' . serialize($this->getState('filter.category_id'));
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.category_id.include');
    $id .= ':' . serialize($this->getState('filter.author_id'));
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.author_id.include');
    $id .= ':' . serialize($this->getState('filter.author_alias'));
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.author_alias.include');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.date_filtering');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.date_field');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.start_date_range');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.end_date_range');
    $id .= ':' . $this->getState('filter.relative_date');

    return parent::getStoreId($id);
}
```

So, the two filter state you need to set states for are:

```
    $model->setState('filter.date_filtering', $range);
```

FYI, it sounds like you are editing the core files directly; which is not recommended since any subsequent Joomla update could over write any customization.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.
I had a problem getting it to work though. After some trial and errors. I got it to work by adding `$model->setState('filter.date_filtering', 'range');` before the code. You can make this edit so that I can mark your response as the correct answer.

Comment: Done, thanks for the feed back.

Comment: Ok. But you removed the other two lines. They are the correct filters to set but won't work without the line I provided. I'll just write out my discoveries as answers below. In case someone else needs them. Thanks again. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

I found two methods of solving this.

.1) Set a date backwards, relative to the current date. (I'm using 60 because I need articles from 2months back)

```
        $model->setState('filter.date_filtering', 'relative');
        $model->setState('filter.relative_date', $params->get('relative_date', 60)); 

        $items = $model->getItems();
```

2) Set any preferred date range

```
    $model->setState('filter.date_filtering', 'range');
    $start_date = strtotime('-2 months');
    $start_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $start_date);
    $end_date = strtotime('now');
    $end_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $end_date);        
    $model->setState('filter.start_date_range', $start_date);
    $model->setState('filter.end_date_range', $end_date);

    $items = $model->getItems();
```

Answer (score 1):

A free module is available at JED that does exactly this. [Most Popular Content by Date Range](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/popular-content/23445) lets you set different date ranges for the popular articles, with options for last day, last 7 days, last 30 days and All time.

[image: Most Popular Content by Date Range module]

Comment: Thanks. But I have already customized the most read module to display images (which it doesn't do by default) + the one you recommended doesn't display images so I still have to do some customization on it + it is a joomla 3 module and I'm on joomla 2.5 ......

Comment: No problem, I see you managed to get your code working, thanks for posting the code. I just wanted to mention this module as it might be useful for other users.